# Batch scripts: find and copy file from unknown directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

I need to make a batch file for my groupmates (actually, I need to make a sequence of the program, but for simple to ask, I use batch file).

The batch's job is copy a specific file in their computer to the batch's folder. But the problem is I don't know the path to that file of all my groupmates.

Here are the things I need:

1. Help my groupmates choose their path to that file. (Maybe just auto-find that file in their computers).
2. Copy that file and paste it into the batch file's folder (which include my other programs).
3. After all my other programs finished their job, copy and replace that file to its original folder.

Do you have any script that might help?

Comment: We need some more information :

What did you have tried as code until now ? what's the name of this file ? or did you know at least some strings in its name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with this batch code :

```
@echo off
Title Search for a file by name (Wildcard accepted) by Hackoo 2014
mode con cols=90 lines=5 & color 9B
echo(
Set /p "FileName=Please Enter the name of the file to find (Wildcard accepted) : "
echo(
Set Tmp=Tmp.txt
Set SearchResult=SearchResult.txt
Call :BrowseFolder "Select the Source folder" "C:\Program"
Set LocationFolder=%MyFolder%
echo You chose to looking into "%LocationFolder%" for this file "%FileName%"
echo( & cls & Color 0A
echo(  & echo  Please Wait for moment .... Searching for "%FileName%" on "%LocationFolder%"
Where /r "%LocationFolder%" "%FileName%" > %Tmp%
Cmd /U /C Type %Tmp% > %SearchResult%
Del %Tmp%
Start %SearchResult%
::******************************************************************************
:BrowseFolder
    set MyFolder=
    set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
    set cmd="%temp%\_.cmd"
    for %%f in (%vbs% %cmd%) do if exist %%f del %%f
    for %%g in ("vbs cmd") do if defined %%g set %%g=
    >%vbs% echo set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    >>%vbs% echo set shell=WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
    >>%vbs% echo set f=shell.BrowseForFolder(0,%1,0,%2) 
    >>%vbs% echo if typename(f)="Nothing" Then  
    >>%vbs% echo wscript.echo "set MyFolder=Dialog Cancelled" 
    >>%vbs% echo WScript.Quit(1)
    >>%vbs% echo end if 
    >>%vbs% echo set fs=f.Items():set fi=fs.Item() 
    >>%vbs% echo p=fi.Path:wscript.echo "set MyFolder=" ^& p
    cscript //nologo %vbs% > %cmd%
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (%cmd%) do %%a
    for %%f in (%vbs% %cmd%) do if exist %%f del %%f
    for %%g in ("vbs cmd") do if defined %%g set %%g=
::******************************************************************************
```

**EDIT : 28/06/2015 at 07:00**

```
@echo off
Title Search for a file by name and copy it (Wildcard accepted) by Hackoo 2015
mode con cols=90 lines=5 & color 9B
Set /p "FileName=Please Enter the name of the file to find (Wildcard accepted) : "
Set SearchResult=SearchResult.txt
Call :BrowseFolder "Select the Source folder" "C:\Program"
Set LocationFolder=%MyFolder%
echo You chose to looking into "%LocationFolder%" for this file "%FileName%"
echo( & cls & Color 0A
echo(  & echo  Please Wait for moment .... Searching for "%FileName%" on "%LocationFolder%"
where /r "%LocationFolder%" "%FileName%" > %SearchResult%
Goto:CopyMyFile
::******************************************************************************
:BrowseFolder
    set MyFolder=
    set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
    set cmd="%temp%\_.cmd"
    for %%f in (%vbs% %cmd%) do if exist %%f del %%f
    for %%g in ("vbs cmd") do if defined %%g set %%g=
    >%vbs% echo set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    >>%vbs% echo set shell=WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
    >>%vbs% echo set f=shell.BrowseForFolder(0,%1,0,%2) 
    >>%vbs% echo if typename(f)="Nothing" Then  
    >>%vbs% echo wscript.echo "set MyFolder=Dialog Cancelled" 
    >>%vbs% echo WScript.Quit(1)
    >>%vbs% echo end if 
    >>%vbs% echo set fs=f.Items():set fi=fs.Item() 
    >>%vbs% echo p=fi.Path:wscript.echo "set MyFolder=" ^& p
    cscript //nologo %vbs% > %cmd%
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (%cmd%) do %%a
    for %%f in (%vbs% %cmd%) do if exist %%f del %%f
    for %%g in ("vbs cmd") do if defined %%g set %%g=
::******************************************************************************
:CopyMyFile
Cls
for /f "delims=*" %%a in (%SearchResult%) do (echo Copy "%%a" "%~dp0" & Copy "%%a" "%~dp0")
Pause
```

Comment: Thank you, It works perfectly. The file name is "rf192.rez" and the destination folder is the batch file's folder. I don't know much about batch code. Could you give me the full code?

Comment: So, when you run this batch file you get the whole path of your file ? and the name of this file is constant for all your groupmates or can be changed ? Can you paste by comment the contents of the file searchresult.txt ?

Comment: The hole part in searchresult.txt: D:\CFQQ\rez\rf192.rez
The name of this file and the folder "rez" can not be change

Comment: Thank you very much, again :) but i have edited a little. [Here's the completed code](http://notepad.cc/completecode)
(I post in there because this have limit characters)

Answer (score 0):

`dir c:\nameoffiletosearch /s /b > %temp%\results.txt` will create a list with full path of all occurences of your file in drive c.

You could even wrap this in a loop that searches multiple drives.

Then get the path from the results.txt and use it with your copy command.